# LINQ: Specified cast is not valid VB.NET, MVC3 Razor

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, razor

this was working yesterday, then today after a bunch of errors i corrected(that seemed to be like the controller had been reverted to an earlier state), i get "Specified cast is not valid." when comparing some fairly direct values. code that generates the error:

```
Dim AssignedRequestIDs = From x In _PITcontext.Sessions Where x.Request_ID > 0 Select     x.Request_ID
Dim result = From r In _PITcontext.Requests Where (Not AssignedRequestIDs.Contains(r.ID)) And (r.NotActive = False) Select r Order By r.NeededByDate Ascending
```

EDIT:

error is on the second line

and the data types are:
 `x.request_ID Integer` (shouldn't ever be null)
 `r.ID Integer` (not Null)
 `r.NotActive Boolean` (not Null)
 `r.neededbydate System.Nullable(Of Date)` obviously nullable
corresponding values in the database have matched datatypes. what could be causing this, and why in the heck isn't there a more verbose error? maybe kick back a column name or between which two variables the conflict occurred... (that'd be too easy i guess)
stack trace is :
    `[InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.]`
    `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Int32() +6712156`
    `Read_Request(ObjectMaterializer`1 ) +6049
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReader`2.MoveNext() +42`
    `System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +165
System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) +520
System.Linq.d__0.MoveNext() +145
System.Linq.Enumerable.Count(IEnumerable`1 source) +267`
    `ASP._Page_Views_Shared__YourRequests_vbhtml.Execute() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\PIT\Views\Shared\_YourRequests.vbhtml:17`
    `System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +280`
    `System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +104`
    `System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +173`
    `System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +378`
    `System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +33`
    `System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +727696
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +265`
    `System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +727652`
    `System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +159`
    `System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +334`
    `System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +62`
    `System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +15`
    `System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +52`
    `System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Wrap>b__3() +15`
    `System.Web.Mvc.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap(Func`1 func) +41
System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer,     Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath,     String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride) +1411`

```
`[HttpException (0x80004005): Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.]`
```

`System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride) +2819`
   `System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage) +275`
   `System.Web.HttpServerUtilityWrapper.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm) +94`
   `System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.ActionHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, TextWriter textWriter) +828`
   `System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.Action(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues) +123`
   `ASP._Page_Views_Home_Index_vbhtml.Execute() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\PIT\Views\Home\Index.vbhtml:44`
   `System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +280`
   `System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +104`
   `System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +143`
   `System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +157`
   `System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +378`
   `System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +33`
   `System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +727696
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +265`
   `System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +727652`
    `System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +159`
    `System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +334`
    `System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +62`
    `System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +15`
    `System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +52`
    `System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606`
    `System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288`

Comment: Try r.NeededByDate.Value, since it is a nullable.

Comment: Which line generates the error?  What's the stack trace?

Comment: Also, if adding the variable names to the exception is so easy, why not post it here so MS can implement it?

Comment: didn't mean that MS would have it easy, but that i would. it was an attempt as a joke. attempt: failed, apparently. (also, i'm clearly not a guru, or i wouldn't need help) but, for the record, all of my errors are as verbose as i can make them. i try not to use error messages like "generic system error".

Comment: `Option Strict On`.  Always.  Also, which line is throwing the `InvalidCastException`?

Comment: `option strict` is on.  
the `Dim result = ` line is the line getting the error. after some further tracing and code-stepping i found it getting the error at `Return Me.GetTable(Of Requests)` and VS won't let me drill deeper than that to see the structure of the query interacting. i tried it with `r.NeededByDate.Value` same issue. i built a view and ran the view, it runs fine, but when i use it in place of the offending `FROM` i get the same error traced to the same place.

Comment: the `dim result = from` is only throwing it because it's getting passed back up the pipe by that `me.GetTable(of T)`

Comment: in the definitions i had a column which stores a "tinyint" that i was calling as if it were an "int" GAWD! **Face-Palm**